# Searching for string and outputting the column

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

So, I'm trying to make someone input a string and make python search for the string in the first column, if found then output the entire row.

How'd I go about doing this? (using gspread)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this is the code:

```
    line = ("abcd")

    try:
       string = input("Please enter a string: ")

       if string in line:
           print(line)
       else:
           print("Your input is not in line.")

    except ValueError:
        print("An error has occured")
```

The `in` statement checks to see if the input is in the text and if it is then it prints it out. (You have to change line to match what you want and for multi-line use `""" text """`). The `try` and `except` statements make the program more robust - especially if you can only enter numbers (integers or floats). It won't crash thus is a good habit to get into. You can google the suffixes for except as there is quite a few.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this, if I run into problems I'll keep you posted.